# Return all levels below a specific member

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssas, mdx

In the following I was hoping to return all of the tree below the member `Engineering`.
I'm guessing I'm misusing `IS`?
Should I be using `membervalue`?
I thought using the specific member would be more efficient?

```
WITH 
    MEMBER [Measures].[LevelName] AS
        [Employee].[Employee Department].Level.Name
    MEMBER [Measures].[LevelNumber] AS
        [Employee].[Employee Department].Level.Ordinal
SELECT
    {
    FILTER(
        [Employee].[Employee Department].AllMembers,
        [Employee].[Employee Department].[Department] IS 
            [Employee].[Employee Department].[Department].&[Engineering]
        )
    } ON 1,
    {
    [Measures].[LevelName],
    [Measures].[LevelNumber] 
    } ON 0
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

Here is the error message:

> Executing the query ... Query (10, 3) The Is function expects a level
>   expression for the 2 argument. A member expression was used. Execution
>   complete

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use the FILTER function to obtain all child members belonging to a specific member. Just do something like this instead:

```
SELECT
{
    [Employee].[Employee Department].[Department].&[Engineering].CHILDREN
} ON 1,
...
```

If you want the entire tree below a specific member, use the DESCENDANTS function:

```
SELECT
{
    DESCENDANTS([Employee].[Employee Department].[Department].&[Engineering],
        [Employee].[Employee Department].[Department], AFTER)
} ON 1,
...
```

Comment: +1 thanks `DESCENDENTS` with `SELF_AND_AFTER` gives me what I want. Would it have been possible with `FILTER` / `IN` ?

Comment: I'm not sure. I doubt it, though, since the logical expression parameter of the FILTER function is evaluated in a different context.

Comment: this idea of **in context / not in context** in `MDX` is still a little alien to me ....do you have any good references to help?

Comment: Take a look at: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff487140.aspx - I unfortunately don't know any good resources focusing exclusively on MDX, but the Wrox series books on Analysis Services usually contain some goodies.